# rich:autocomplete cachedAjax firing after prefix

Tags: autocomplete, richfaces

I´m trying to use the *rich:autocomplete* component with the *cachedAjax* mode to get the list from the server after a short prefix and process the remain autocomplete on the client, but it keeps firing the *autocompleteMethod* after every character after the minChars param.

Anyone else had this problem? Or maybe I´m doing somethin wrong?
I´m using Richfaces 4.5.3.Final and the xhtml and the function on the bean are listed bellow:

XHTML

```
<h:form>
    <h3>Test cached</h3>
    <rich:autocomplete mode="cachedAjax" minChars="3" autocompleteMethod="#{beanTesteLogan.doAutoComplete}"/>
</h:form>
```

Function on bean

```
public List<String> doAutoComplete(String pattern) throws SQLException {

    List<String> listaSaida = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
    List<Pessoa> pessoas = PessoaDAO.findByNomeLike(connection, pattern);

    for (Pessoa pessoa : pessoas) {
        listaSaida.add(pessoa.getNome());
    }

    return listaSaida;
}
```

Comment: What are you typing in? If you go from "abc" to "abcd" then the ajax request shouldn't fire, the JavaScript method `onChangeValue` should find that "abcd" is cached.

Comment: When I type "abc" to "abcd" or "abcde" the ajax request is fired, but when I type something with a lot more characters that _minChars_, like "abcdefgh", then the ajax does not fire. The strange is there is not a fixed lenght that stops firing the ajax request.

Comment: Looking at your code if you're retrieving the items from database each time then the requests are probably firing faster than your application can process them.